# expose kibana through subpath on kubernetes cluster via ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kibana

I have elastic operator installed and running on my kubernetes cluster and I want to be able to access kibana through the `/kibana` subpath. I have an ingress that is configured like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-kb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules: 
  - host: ""
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /kibana(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kb-qs-kb-http
            port:
              number: 5601
```

What does the yaml file for my kibana instance have to look like, so that it is accessible through `/kibana` path?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "localhost" #OR YOUR HOST
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/kibana"
            backend:
              service:
                name: kb-qs-kb-http
                port:
                  number: 5601
```

Also take a look at this link to have a clearer understanding of how the NGINX rewrite works:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: Also this can help to understand: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that, but when I try to access it from my browser I just get a 404. What do I have to specify in he kibana config yml file?